# save default value in Downshift Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

how to show default value, when user open it, it should show default value, and the user can also change it too. I have used from here,
link- https://scotch.io/tutorials/5-most-common-dropdown-use-cases-solved-with-react-downshift#toc-downshift-with-axios
This code is under MF.jsx in return.

```
<Downshift
        onChange={downshiftOnChange}
        itemToString={(item) => (item ? item._source.name : "")}
      >
        {({
          selectedItem,
          getInputProps,
          getItemProps,
          highlightedIndex,
          isOpen,
          inputValue,
          getLabelProps,
        }) => (
          <div>
            <label
              style={{ marginTop: "1rem", display: "block" }}
              {...getLabelProps()}
            >
              Mutual Fund scheme Name
            </label>
            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: "Enter Mutual Fund Name...",
                onChange: changeInput,
                style: { width: "100%" },
                value: props.values,
              })}
            />
            {isOpen ? (
              <div className="downshift-dropdown">
                {list.map((item, index) => (
                  <div
                    className="dropdown-item"
                    {...getItemProps({ key: index, index, item })}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor:
                        highlightedIndex === index ? "lightgray" : "white",
                      fontWeight: selectedItem === item ? "bold" : "normal",
                    }}
                  >
                    {item._source.name}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        )}
      </Downshift>
```

inside input tag, in values  i have passed the props.values, it shows the data from the parent but, i am unable to change any thing in input. if you know downshift. please tell how can i do? 
i want data loaded from props. and i can change it too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **defaultValue** value instead of **value** inside the *getInputProps*

Answer (score 0):

One option is to ditch the `Downshift` component for the `useCombobox` hook. Then one can specify:

```js
initialInputValue: initialValue, // sets when initialized
defaultInputValue: initialValue, // sets on reset or when an item is selected
```

Docs:

- [initialinputvalue](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift/tree/master/src/hooks/useCombobox#initialinputvalue)
- [defaultinputvalue](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift/tree/master/src/hooks/useCombobox#defaultinputvalue)